# How to Parse Html tags From Website in Android

Tags: android, html-parsing

i am trying to get the text in the tags below from the 
URL:`http://www.mcpss.com/?PN='News2'&SubP='DNewsStory'&gn=&NewsID=47318&ShowNav=&StoryGroup=Current`

```
<td class="header">

OPEN HOUSE SCHEDULED AT CLARK-SHAW

</td>

<p><span style="font-size: 12pt;">January 16, 2013 - Due to the relocation of Murphy High School to the Clark-Shaw campus and the necessary construction that is still ongoing, Clark-Shaw school did not participate in the magnet school &ldquo;See and Sign&rdquo; January 11 and 12<sup>th</sup>. We would like to resume giving school tours and meeting interested parents. Therefore, we are planning an &ldquo;Open House&rdquo; on Friday, January 25 from 9:00 a.m.- 12:00 p.m. to coincide with our school&rsquo;s Science Fair Open House that is scheduled for that day.</span></p>
<p><span style="font-size: 12pt;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p><span style="font-size: 12pt;">Please share this information with your friends and neighbors.&nbsp;&nbsp; Magnet School applications are available now online.</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

i want to represent the text in android application like below:

*OPEN HOUSE SCHEDULED AT CLARK-SHAW

January 16, 2013 - Due to the relocation of Murphy High School to the Clark-Shaw campus and the necessary construction that is still ongoing, Clark-Shaw school did not participate in the magnet school “See and Sign” January 11 and 12th. We would like to resume giving school tours and meeting interested parents. Therefore, we are planning an “Open House” on Friday, January 25 from 9:00 a.m.- 12:00 p.m. to coincide with our school’s Science Fair Open House that is scheduled for that day.

Please share this information with your friends and neighbors.   Magnet School applications are available now online.*

how can i acheive it in android.

Comment: actually my doubt is how to select a particular <td class="header"> and <p> tags i don't knoow how to give the query path

Comment: Why don't you try to load a page in `webview`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using jsoup http://jsoup.org/ you can get this

download the jsoup.jar file then add it to your libs folder then go to android dependancies right click >> build path >> configure build path >> ADD JARS>> libs >> then choose the jsoup.jar file you downloaded

```
 try {
      String website="http://www.mcpss.com/?PN='News2'&SubP='DNewsStory'&gn=&NewsID=47318&ShowNav=&StoryGroup=Current";
      Document doc = Jsoup.connect(website).get();
      Elements el=doc.getElementsByClass("header");
      String text=el.text();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.wtf("name of activity","error message to show in log", e);
    }
```

Comment: how can i parse a particular <p> tag from the following  p tags above

Comment: doc.getElementsByTag("nameoftag");

after you get the elements loop through them for the specific <p> tag you are looking for...no doubt there will be many other <p> tags that the function picked up

Comment: in the above url there are lot of <p><span style="font-size: 12pt;">January 16, 2013 - Due to the relocation of Murphy High School to the Clark-Shaw campus and the necessary construction that is still ongoing, Clark-Shaw school did not participate in the magnet school &ldquo;See and Sign&rdquo; January 11 and 12<sup>th</sup>. We would like to resume giving school tours and meeting interested parents.</span></p> tags how can i identify a particular <p> tag.

Comment: not sure if there is any way specifically since these tags don't have any identifier with them....if you have access to the website you can add ids to come with the tags that way your app can pick them up....if you don't have access i'm afraid you might have to just loop through the tags filtering out the ones you don't want

Comment: note that if you are going to use the method i told you (looping through the tags) you might want to do it on a server then have that server send the result to your app....because it is a costing process which will cause a bit of a lag in the app

Comment: there is no xpath query in android similar to iphone

Comment: yea but what you can do is
String total="";
for(Element e: el){ 
String a=e.toString();
if(a.contains("textyouarelookingfor"){
total=total+a;
}
}
that way you loop through the code looking for what you want

Answer (score 1):

As this is Html document, try to use Html.fromHtml(string) for TextView or try to use webview depends on tags.

For TextView you can use this like

```
TextView txt=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        String str="<td class=\"header\">"+
        "OPEN HOUSE SCHEDULED AT CLARK-SHAW"+
        "</td>"+
        "<p><span style=\"font-size: 12pt;\">January 16, 2013 - Due to the relocation of Murphy High School to the Clark-Shaw campus and the necessary construction that is still ongoing, Clark-Shaw school did not participate in the magnet school &ldquo;See and Sign&rdquo; January 11 and 12<sup>th</sup>. We would like to resume giving school tours and meeting interested parents. Therefore, we are planning an &ldquo;Open House&rdquo; on Friday, January 25 from 9:00 a.m.- 12:00 p.m. to coincide with our school&rsquo;s Science Fair Open House that is scheduled for that day.</span></p>"+
        "<p><span style=\"font-size: 12pt;\">&nbsp;</span></p>"+
        "<p><span style=\"font-size: 12pt;\">Please share this information with your friends and neighbors.&nbsp;&nbsp; Magnet School applications are available now online.</span></p>"+
        "<p>&nbsp;</p>";

        txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

For WebView try to use webview.loadData();